# How to create a password input with fabric ui react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

There is a TextField input in fabric ui, but I have not found a way to create a password field for a login form.

Edit:

I tried using the 'type' attribute but I get an error.

```
Property 'type' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TextField> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>
```

These are the related packages from package.json:

```
"office-ui-fabric-react": "^4.21.4",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"typescript": "^2.4.2"
```

This problem seems to be similar to mine: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/2203 - I tried downgrading to TypeScript 2.2.2 but I get a ton of errors from the node_modules folder if I do that.

UPDATE: issue is fixed now. Updated packages and it's no longer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<TextField defaultValue='foo' name='bar' type='password' />
```

See this issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/1127

And this issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/574

**UPDATE with response from my issue on github:**

[Go to my issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/2247#issuecomment-316439599)

micahgodbolt:

This was fixed sometime ago it seems. I have no trouble doing:

```
<TextField type='password' label='Default TextField'  />
```

and getting this:

[image: image provided by the user micahgodbolt on the issue]

If it's a typescript issue, we're working out some bugs with the most recent version of TS. Make sure you've updated to the most recent version of Fabric. I.E. it has nothing to do with text field and type password.

Comment: Take a look at this issue:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/2203

Comment: I'm looking at the issue and if I downgrade Typescript to version 2.2.2 I start getting errors from node_modules folder. Weird. Trying to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: I opened an issue on github and linked your question there: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/2247

Comment: maybe there is a better place to find the answer, if they help us solve the problem, i will edit my response with the new information for other people that seems to have the same problem as you

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will update my post if I find a solution meanwhile.

Comment: @KrisztiánNagy, i received a answer on my issue on github. Take a look at my response

Comment: I updated my packages, yet it still gives the same error. (fabric-react: 4.21.4; typescript 2.4.2)

Comment: I just tried npm start with having set type as password, the error appears, but the textfield is working and it covers the password.

Comment: well, let me know if you solved this error, but i think that the problem isn't the textfield itself.

Comment: i think you can delete your node_modules folder and then run npm install to make a fresh install of the packages.

Comment: I thought about that and tried it and the error message persists :(

Answer (score 1):

set `type="password"`

```
<TextField type="password" />
```

see also [TextField type="password" · Issue #490 · OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react · GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/490)